# What is the blue liquid in SteamWorld Heist?

Tags: steamworld-heist

In the later phase of the game there is often a blue liquid falling from the tubes in the ceiling. Some enemies have guns which fire this liquid. It always stays on the floor.

Does this liquid have any effect on steambots? What is its purpose in the game?

[image: Blue liquid is on the floor]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Brjann of Image & Form here, the happy people that made/make SteamWorld Heist. :) The liquid is diesel, which is flammable. Standing right beneath or near a drip is not very good, as the place you're then standing in will be drenched in it - and that makes you extra vulnerable to shots, since it will catch on fire if hit. Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Welcome to Arqade, Brjann. Always nice to see devs themselves taking interest in our site. May I suggest registering for an account? Should make tracking the tag for your game easier and the reputation you'd gather would allow for wider range of prilvages, like commenting on the questions if you want to ask for clarifications.