# How much damage does ignited oil do?

Tags: steamworld-heist

Starting in the second area, (The Core), some missions have ceiling tubes that drip [blue liquid diesel](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/282865/181240). Shooting oil will light it on fire, dealing extra damage to anyone standing on it.

Because most weapons have a degree of luck-based damage variance, I haven’t been able to figure out how worried I should be about standing on flammable liquids.

**How much damage does oil do when ignited?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignited oil seems to do 2 damage per player unit standing in it, according to [this Steam guide](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=828869751):

> Oil patches from pipe leaks, oil barrels or oil grenades can be
>   detonated with a single projectile (bullet) and will do 2 damage to
>   all player units standing in it. (WHAT ABOUT ENEMIES ? DOES 5 damage
>   to enemies).

This quote can be found in the last part of the guide, "Miscellaneous damage mechanics related observations".